# Multiple models generic DetailView to template

Tags: django, django-views

I have 2 models and I got the `IndexView` working properly using the `get_context_data` method. However my `DetailView` using the same technique is not working. How do I simply get 2 models into the `DetailView`?

views.py

```
from .models import CharacterSeries, CharacterUniverse


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'character/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'character_series_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return CharacterSeries.objects.order_by('name')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['character_universe_list'] = CharacterUniverse.objects.order_by('name')
        return context


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = CharacterSeries
    template_name = 'character/detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['character_universe_list'] = CharacterUniverse.objects.all()
        return context
```

I am missing something; I need to get `CharacterUniverse` into the DetailView. I have tried using [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#making-friendly-template-contexts)'s information to no avail.

Thanks all.

**UPDATE:**

detail.html

```
<ul>
{% for series in characterseries.character_set.all %}
    <li>{{ series.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<ul>
{% for universe in characteruniverse.character_set.all %}
    <li>{{ universe.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

index.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'character/style.css' %}" />

<h1>Character Series</h1>

<ul>
  {% for character_series in character_series_list %}  {# for MODEL in .. #}
    <li><a href="{% url 'character:detail' character_series.pk %}">{{ character_series.name }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

<h1>Character Universe</h1>

<ul>
  {% for character_universe in character_universe_list %}  {# for MODEL in .. #}
    <li><a href="{% url 'character:detail' character_universe.pk %}">{{ character_universe.name }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**An example from the official documentation: This is not possible in my case?**

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from books.models import Publisher, Book

class PublisherDetail(DetailView):

    model = Publisher

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(PublisherDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
        context['book_list'] = Book.objects.all()
        return context
```

Perhaps this is the final solution? This is not working though.. Naming wrong?

---

***ALL THE UPDATES***

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from .models import CharacterSeries, CharacterUniverse


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'character/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'character_series_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return CharacterSeries.objects.order_by('name')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['character_universe_list'] = CharacterUniverse.objects.order_by('name')
        return context


class SeriesDetail(DetailView):
    model = CharacterSeries
    template_name = 'character/series_detail.html'

class UniverseDetail(DetailView):
    model = CharacterUniverse
    template_name = 'character/universe_detail.html'
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.SeriesDetail.as_view(), name='series_detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.UniverseDetail.as_view(), name='universe_detail'),
]
```

**index.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'character/style.css' %}" />

<h1>Character Series</h1>

<ul>
  {% for character_series in character_series_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'character:series_detail' character_series.pk %}">{{ character_series.name }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

<h1>Character Universe</h1>

<ul>
  {% for character_universe in character_universe_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'character:universe_detail' character_universe.pk %}">{{ character_universe.name }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**series_detail.html**

```
<ul>
{% for series in characterseries.character_set.all %}
    <li>{{ series.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**universe_detail.html**

```
<ul>
{% for universe in characteruniverse.character_set.all %}
    <li>{{ universe.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: @Alasdair I am getting a 404 (page not found) error when I click the character universe links. The character series links work fine and go to the detail.html.

Comment: @Alasdair please check my update. I put up the detail.html file.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do. I don't see any links in the template you have posted. In your `get_context_data`, you include all of the `CharacterUniverse` objects as `character_universe_list`, but in the template you refer to `characteruniverse`. It's not clear where you think `characteruniverse` has come from.

Comment: @Alasdair I am adding the index.html where my links are. Hope this helps.

Comment: A `DetailView` is meant to display details about an object from one model. It's fine to include extra context, but the view isn't designed to handle two possible models. I suggest you create a second detail view to display a particular character universe.

Comment: @Alasdair ok now we are getting somewhere. I updated the main question to include an example I have been looking at from the official docs. Is it possible or not? Thanks.

Comment: @Alasdair see the example is using 2 models though; ``Publisher`` and ``Book``. But is this not a "generic" view perhaps that's why?

Comment: That example is showing the details for one publisher, and displaying all the books at the same time. Your `DetailView` lets you show the details for one `CharacterSeries`, and display all of the `CharacterUniverse` at the same time. However, you cannot use the same view to display details for one `CharacterUniverse`. Therefore, it doesn't make sense to link to `{% url 'character:detail' character_universe.pk %}`.

Comment: @Alasdair So what is the best way to write 2 ``DetailView``s separately? Can I just write 2 generic ``DetailView``s back to back?

Comment: Yes, just define two different views, one for each model. Make sure they are both named differently, and create a different url pattern for each one.

Comment: @Alasdair I updated the answer with 2 ``DetailViews``s. Though it is not working; the 2nd one ``UniverseDetail`` still won't load, but ``SeriesDetail`` works. Whatever comes first loads, 2nd doesn't.. I think it is the names.

Comment: You need to show the urls for both views, and the links for both.

Comment: @Alasdair Ok I did a final lengthy update to the question. Underneath the line you will find all my files. The views, templates, and urls. Still not working. Very close though. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Explanation of why you can't use one view for both models

A `DetailView` is meant to display details about an object from one model. It's fine to include extra context, but the view isn't designed to handle two possible models.

The example from the docs is showing the details for one publisher, and displaying all the books at the same time.

Your DetailView lets you show the details for one CharacterSeries, and display all of the CharacterUniverse at the same time.

However, you cannot use that same view to display details for one `CharacterUniverse`. You need a different view to display details for one `CharacterUniverse`

## Solution

Therefore, you need two different detail views, one for each model.

You need a distinct url for each view. Otherwise, the request will always match the first regex (in this case `series_detail`. The following would work.

```
url(r'^series/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.SeriesDetail.as_view(), name='series_detail'),
url(r'^universe/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.UniverseDetail.as_view(), name='universe_detail'),
```