# How can I use an extended user model in a DetailView?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I've got a Django view in charge of showing a user profile. I'm using the user model provided by django itself but I also would like to extend it with some of my own information, So I made my own model to extend the user model itself:

```
class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser):
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    current_profile = models.ImageField(default=static('img/default_profile.jpg'))
    ratings = models.ManyToManyField(Video, through='UserProfileVideoRating', related_name='ratings')
    views = models.ManyToManyField(Video, through='UserProfileVideoView', related_name='views')
    CommentRating = models.ManyToManyField(Comment, through='UserProfileCommentRating', related_name='CommentRating')
    subscriptions = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

And here is my view I'd like to use for that:

```
User = get_user_model()
# Create your views here.

class profileDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'profile.html'

    def get_object(self):
        username = self.kwargs.get("username")
        if username is None:
            raise Http404
        return get_object_or_404(User, username__iexact=username, is_active=True)
```

Now my question is, seeing as [DetailViews are meant for a single model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31146275/multiple-models-generic-detailview-to-template), How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You're confused between two ways of extending the built-in User model.

If you're inheriting from AbstractBaseUser, that means you're defining your *own* user model - you would need to define its own username/email fields etc, and set the AUTH_USER_MODEL to point to your replacement model. In this case, you wouldn't need to reference two models in your template because your model would *be* the User.

However if you want to define a related UserProfile, you don't need to inherit from AbstractBaseUser, and you don't need to change AUTH_USER_MODEL; but you *do* need to define a relation with the actual User model, probably via a one-to-one field. In this case, to get access to the profile you just follow the relationship in the template - eg via `{{ user.userprofile.currentprofile }}` etc.

In your case I would advise taking the second option; remove the inheritance from AbstractBaseUser and add a one-to-one field to User.

Comment: so I would add something like this: `user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='User')` and then I can just access it like this: `user.UserProfile.someotherfield` right?

Comment: Yes except the value of related_name is the accessor: in the case you show, `user.User`. But I would advise leaving out that parameter, and using the default: `user.userprofile.someotherfield`.

Comment: So I tried doing: `<img src="{{ user.userprofile.profile_picture }}">` but it's not showing up.

Comment: the src value is completely empty

Comment: Can you try adding a print statement to the profileDetailView.get_object to see if the user model correctly has the attribute you're looking for set? Something like:

user_obj = get_object_or_404(User, username__iexact=username, is_active=True)
print(user_obj.current_profile.profile_picture).
return user_obj. If that errors out, it's because you're not using your custom user model. If it prints nothing, it's because the profile picture isn't set in ways that you expect.

Comment: Have you actually defined a UserProfile related to the logged in user?

Comment: yes I have but for now I just set the 'profile_picture' to a testing string 'test'. however this should still show up inside the src value i think