# Using django-filter with class DetailView

Tags: django, django-filter, django-generic-views

I want to make a dynamic filtering form with Django and django-filter like stackoverflow filter
[image]

and i want to use this filter on a template that render by DetailView , now the problem is i searched alot and i didn't found example of how to make this happen

in my template i list all 'courses' that related to 'materials' class
and i want to make a form on the same template so i can filter this list

my template

```
{% for course in material_detail.courses_set.all %}
<div class="course">
    <h5>{{ course.course_name }}</h5>
    <p>{{ course.course_description }} </p>            
</div>
<hr/>
{% endfor %}
```

I have two models 'Materials' and 'Courses' 
my models.py

```
class Materials(models.Model):
    materials_name          = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    materials_description   = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    slug_material           = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)


class Courses(models.Model):
    course_name             = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    course_description      = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
    material                = models.ForeignKey(Materials, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

and i have one Class DetailView
my views.py

```
class MaterialsDetailView(DetailView):
    model               = Materials
    template_name       = 'tuts/material.html'
    context_object_name = 'material_detail'
```

I have made a filters.py file and make this code on it , but i don't know how to link this with my Class DetailView

```
import django_filters

from .models import Materials

class CourseFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

class Meta:
    model = Materials
    fields = ['courses__course_name', 'courses__course_description']
```

**Note:**
there are more code on my models and template i remove it to make the code very simple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are just displaying the **course list** related to the **material**. So you can filter related courses with `f = CourseFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=Courses.objects.filter(material=material_pk))`. Notice I m using the `CourseFilter` instead of `MaterialFilter`

views.py

```
class MaterialsDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Materials
    template_name = 'tuts/material.html'
    context_object_name = 'material_detail'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context_data = super(MaterialsDetailView, self).get_context_data()
        material_pk = self.kwargs.get('pk', None)
        f = CourseFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=Courses.objects.filter(material=material_pk))
        context_data['filter'] = f
        return context_data
```

filters.py

```
class CourseFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Courses
        fields = []
    course_name = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name="course_name", lookup_expr="icontains")
    course_description = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name="course_description", lookup_expr="icontains")
```

In your template, you can access all your **filtered queryset** in `filter.qs` and the corresponding form in `filter.form`

tuts/material.html

```
<form method="GET">
    {{ filter.form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
{% for course in filter.qs %}
<div class="course">
    <h5>{{ course.course_name }}</h5>
    <p>{{ course.course_description }} </p>
</div>
<hr/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: There is no ImageFilter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ListView instead and filter with get_queryset(), then call get_context_data() to return the keyword arguments as the context to your template.

Then just wire up a separate URL conf for each filter you need. You can use the same template for each view, just link to the URL conf with an href in the template, pass a URL parameter as a keyword argument and access it with self.kwargs['name_of_parameter'] in your view. Then filter by that parameter in the view to get a queryset that you then return back to the template.

Blog example:

```
class PostCategoryFilter(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    template_name = 'blog/post_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(category=self.kwargs['category_id'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostCategoryFilter, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        context['filtered_category'] = Category.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['category_id'])

        return context
```

Anything in the context you can then use as variables in your template, so you'll have categories and the filtered posts for example.

Comment: thanks for your replay, i can't use ListView instead of  DetailView because i list 'courses' related to 'materials' , for example if i have material its name is 'django' then i want to list all courses related to this 'django material '  this is way i use DetailView

Comment: It is not best practice to handle multiple models within a DetailView. See the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31146275/multiple-models-generic-detailview-to-template. You can achieve what you need by combining both models into a ListView as shown above.

Comment: But i don't handle multiple models within DetailView .. the model i use 'Materials' is related to another model 'Courses' .. so in my DetailView i only use 'Materials' Models and in template i list all Courses objects related to this Materials ( and this list what i want to filter )

Comment: I have searched a lot and i didn't see any examples to make this happen is this something impossible ?